# Stringizing in RPG?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to use the name of variables as literals/strings to call a procedure. Looking for a procedure/api/anything to simulate the Stringizing Operator from C. Is it even possible?

```
myField = Value;
myProc(stringize(myField):myField);


dcl-proc myProc;
dcl-pi;
   variableName char(10);
   value        char(10);
end-pi;
   dsply (variableName + ': ' + value);
end-proc;
```

expected result:
myField: Value

Answer (score 3):

No. That is not even a C operator, but an artifact of macro expansion. The C pre-compiler performs the expansion. There is nothing in the RPG compiler that does this. You could ask for this feature by submitting an RFE on [developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).

However, I don't really understand the need. The C macro just turns the parameter name into text like this:

```
#define stringize(x) #x

a = stringize(test);
```

results in `a = "test";`

why not just use `a = "test";`

In RPG also why not just use `a = 'test';`

or in your example `myProc('myfield': myfield);`

what does `stringize(myfield)` accomplish?